# SENDINBLUE API (PHP)

Tags: php, api

quisiera saber como insertar datos a una lista, createcontact(), ahora bien ya puedo insertar el email a una lista determinada pero, quiero subir más datos además del email, datos como nombre, telefono, etc...son campos personalizados que anexe en la plataforma web. estuve investigando sobre el valor attributes al crear contacto pero al insertar debe ser de tipo object, no entiendo que objeto o como? me podrían ayudar?

require_once('./autoload.php');

```
// Configure API key authorization: api-key
SendinBlue\Client\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setApiKey('api-key', 'API_KEY');
// Uncomment below to setup prefix (e.g. Bearer) for API key, if needed
// SendinBlue\Client\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setApiKeyPrefix('api-key', 'Bearer');

$api_instance = new SendinBlue\Client\Api\ContactsApi();
$createContact = new \SendinBlue\Client\Model\CreateContact(); // \SendinBlue\Client\Model\CreateContact | Values to create a contact

$createContact['email'] = 'email@gmail.com';
$createContact['attributes'] = array("NOMBRE"=>"contacto contacto", "SMS"=>"9998887772", "PERFIL"=>"ALGO");
$createContact['listIds'] = array(7);

try {
    $result = $api_instance->createContact($createContact);
    print_r($result);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception when calling ContactsApi->createContact: ', $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir un poco de más información? Tal vez algunos fragmentos del código que estás trabajando

Comment: ya está editado...

Comment: Y que te devuelve el $e->getMessage() cuando ejecutas el código?

Comment: Exception when calling ContactsApi->createContact: [400] Error connecting to the API (https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/contacts)

si elimino la linea de código de attributes, funciona correctamente

Comment: alguien que me ayude?